# set UINavigationBar color dependent on view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I want to set the UINavigationBar color per view controller, not in the app delegate, as that would be done like this.

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
```

I have looked around and just cant find how to do this.I tried doing it like this but it did not work:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }
```

How do I set the color dependent on the view controller and not globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you will need to have code in each view controller to set the nav bar colour.  Try adding this code to the `viewDidLoad` for each of your view controllers:

```
if let navController = self.navigationController {
    navController.navigationBar.tintColor = self.view.tintColor
}
```

This will make the nav bar's tint colour whatever the view controller's tint colour is, but you can obviously change this to any colour you want.

The beauty of this is you can literally just copy paste this without having to change anything, so it is really easy to implement across multiple view controllers (as there are no specific references to the name of the view controller).

I hope this helps.

Comment: This did not work for me. This programmatically is the same as what I had tried 'self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()' It is clever though the have it be the view's own tintColor; however, this isn not working for me.

Comment: I had to remove my custom class for this to work. It is as if the custom UINavigationController class was interfering with the code in the view controller.

Comment: Glad you could get it working.  When you say your custom class, do you mean you created a custom class which inherited the properties of the UINavigationController class?

Comment: Yeah! It was just a subclass.

Comment: Ok.  My initial thought is that you might not have subclassed it correctly and the subclass might not have inherited the properties of the super class.  The documentation is really good in this area: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html)